# Inserting rows for specific missing values

Tags: excel, vba

I know how to insert rows for sequential missing values, but how can I do this for unique values that I store in a range? For example:

```
Range of all needed values          New list with missing values
2                                   2
3                                   5
5                                   7
6                                   15
7
10
15
```

The code below adds rows in a sequence (i.e. if list is 2 3 5, it adds 4) so it's not what I need but I don't know how to make it loop through a range and take values only from it

```
Sub RowsInSequence()
    Dim i   As Long, j  As Long
    i = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For j = i To 1 Step -1
        If Cells(j + 1, 1) <> "" Then
            If Cells(j + 1, 1).Value - Cells(j, 1).Value > 1 Then
                x = Cells(j + 1, 1).Value - Cells(j, 1).Value
                Rows(j + 1 & ":" & x + j - 1).Insert
            End If
        End If
    Next j
    With Range("A1:A" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
        .Formula = "=Row()"
        .Value = .Value
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: is there any chance that the list with missing values can be scrambled like 2,7,15,5 or they are always in the same order with original list only with missing cells?

Comment: it has to be in the same order

Comment: please post the code you have made to try to get this to work for yourself. We can help you more easily and efficiently if you post this.

Comment: In the end will the list be identical or will there be numbers in list 2 that is not in list 1?

Comment: I seek it to be completely identical Scott. Just need the rows inserted where specific values from another list should be

Comment: iterate through the first list.  Use `Find` or a second loop to test whether it exists in the second list.  If not add the line to the bottom of list 2.  When done sort on the ID value.  Try working through this and when you get stuck on something specific then come back and ask the specific question posting the part of the code that is giving trouble.  I assume since you did not respond to Scott Holtzman's question that you have no code to show.  SO is not a code for me site.

Comment: Thanks Scott. Naturally I didn't yet have a code as I said I can only figure out how to do it in sequence which doesn't help me in any way. I don't have enough knowledge to add the part where it compares values from another column. But as requested I've now added the code.